# Apache Commons FTP: isPositivePreliminary returns false (code 550)

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using Apache Commons' FTPClient to talk to an FTP server and upload some file. Inside the code, I discovered that the function isPositivePreliminary() returns false, because the reply code it gets is 550. The same code acts differently (with no problems) accessing other FTP sites.

However, when I try to open a regular FTP connection in shell with the same address, user and password - everything works just fine: going into passive mode, uploading and renaming a file.

So what gives? Why can't my code access it? I'm guessing it's something in the remote FTP configuration, but what do I need to tell my customer?

Comment: I know what it is (for future reference): 
Error 550 states that "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.". In my code, I tried uploading a file that had colons in its name, which this particular FTP server didn't like.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer?

Comment: Hi Paulo - sorry I just saw your question. Well I didn't actually change the code. Instead, I did the right thing: told the customer they should change their settings.. But seriously, the colons were in a filename I picked up, so I'll have to change that default to something else. I'm not sure I want to dive into escaping filenames, if I can help it..

Comment: btw, did you know that you don't get email notification on comments? weird..

Comment: (I don't use email notifications at all, so no, I didn't know.) Simply put in an answer what you wrote here as comments, (and then accept it). (I don't like unanswered questions which in fact are not open anymore, they steal my time when I browse the unanswered questions tab.)

Comment: Paulo, I'm not that proficient with this site, so didn't know what 'answer' you meant - so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what it is (for future reference): Error 550 states that "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.". In my code, I tried uploading a file that had colons in its name, which this particular FTP server didn't like.

-dbg